# Why doesn't port forwarding work for me?

Tags: networking, router, port-forwarding, port

I've tried to use port forwarding for a while now, I had 2 different routers and internet suppliers and for both of them, it didn't work. I've tried many ways to do it and none of them worked. Looked in a lot of guides and asked a lot of people why it doesn't work but no one seems to know.
What can cause the problem if I did everything right (I did the exact same thing in my friend's house and it worked), and the problem is probably not in the internet supplier because we changed it?

I have a hotbox router from the company HOT. I used to have Netgear router from the company Bezeq (Those are common routers in my country).
I tried the basic port forwarding, adding it via the router site from the default gateway and trying to access it but nothing works. Tried a few more tricks that didn't work as well and now I'm stuck not knowing what can I do.

Comment: I don't have two routers, I had one, it didn't work for him than it got replaced for other reason and it didn't work for him as well. Also what do you mean by the more internal device? my computer?

Comment: Why are you asking the same question again? Please don't do that, read and take note of [What does it mean if a question is "closed"?](https://superuser.com/help/closed-questions). If you have new information you should edit it into the original question instead of deleting it and asking a new one.

Comment: sorry, thought the closed means that no one can see the question.

Comment: Sorry, I missed the "used to" before the netgear.

Comment: You cannot use your default gateway address to test your port forwarding. You have to access your external address, given by your provider. You can view your current external address on sites like [ifconfig.io](http://ifconfig.io/). Access this address on your forwarded port and the forwarding should work.

Comment: Yes, of course. I am saying I did manage to open ports on a friend's router and access it from my network. I know how to open a port but for some reason, it doesn't work

Comment: *"It doesn't work"* - Please consider [edit]ing you question to explain (in detail) your exact setup and steps you are taking now. Ideally, a the very least, this should likely include setting examples for your router and the service(s)/devices you are trying to access, as well as how you are attempting to access those services (from the local network, from your phone, etc.)  and the specific errors/messages you are encountering.